# how to get the asp.net drop down list items in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one dropdownlist in my c# code behind page like
`DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
            dl.Items.Add("Item 2");

```
        dl.Items.FindByText("Item 2").Value="2";
        dl.Items.Add("Item 3");

        dl.Items.FindByText("Item 3").Value="3";`
```

I like to get that drop down list items in client side java script. one important think note that I like to get values of dropdownlist in the c# code behind page and not the asp.net page. Can anyone know the solution for that problem?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ddl= document.getElementById("<%=ddl.ClientID%>");
var Text = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text; 
var Value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

"View source" in your browser, find the drop down, then code your Javascript accordingly.